# SQL Selecting Distinct Count of items where 2 conditions are met

Tags: sql, count, group-by, distinct

I am struggling to get a DISTINCT COUNT working with SQL DISTINCT SELECT

Not sure if I should even be using distinct here, but I have got it correct using a subquery, though it is very heavy processing wise.

This query does what I ultimately want results wise (without the weight)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
product_brandNAME, 
product_classNAME, 
  (SELECT COUNT(productID) FROM products 
   WHERE products.product_classID = product_class.product_classID 
   AND products.product_brandID = product_brand.product_brandID) as COUNT
FROM products
JOIN product_brand
JOIN product_class
ON  products.product_brandID = product_brand.product_brandID
AND products.product_classID = product_class.product_classID
GROUP BY productID
ORDER BY product_brandNAME
```

This gets close, and is much more efficient, but I can't get the count working, it only counts (obviously) the distinct count which is 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_brandNAME, product_classNAME, COUNT(*) as COUNT
FROM products
JOIN product_brand
JOIN product_class
ON  products.product_brandID = product_brand.product_brandID
AND products.product_classID = product_class.product_classID
GROUP BY productID
ORDER BY product_brandNAME
```

Any suggestions, I'm sure its small, and have been researching the net for hours for an answer to no avail for 2 conditions to match.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following query

**Edit**

```
SELECT  product_brandNAME
        , product_classNAME
        , COUNT(*)
FROM    products
        JOIN product_brand ON products.product_brandID = product_brand.product_brandID
        JOIN product_class ON products.product_classID = product_class.product_classID              
GROUP BY 
        product_brandNAME
        , product_classNAME
```

Comment: Thanks Lieven, that was close to right, but put me on the right track, I just took out the |GROUP BY 'productID'|, and its a winner, thanks so much, saved me tons of time :)

Answer (score 0):

When using GROUP BY you do not need to use a DISTINCT clause. Try the following:

```
SELECT productID,
       product_brandNAME, 
       product_classNAME, 
       COUNT(*) as COUNT 
  FROM products JOIN product_brand ON  products.product_brandID = product_brand.product_brandID
                JOIN product_class ON products.product_classID = product_class.product_classID       
GROUP BY productID,
         product_brandNAME, 
         product_classNAME 
ORDER BY product_brandNAME
```